# Changing wp7 webbrowser forecolor

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

I written code like

```
<phone:WebBrowser x:Name="wbLogin" 
                  LoadCompleted="wbLogin_LoadCompleted" 
                  IsScriptEnabled="True" Margin="0,0,0,34"/>
```

I want to change this webbrowser forecolor / page color to be displayed in different color (Cyan in case). So I taken code like,

```
<phone:WebBrowser x:Name="wbLogin" 
                  LoadCompleted="wbLogin_LoadCompleted" 
                  IsScriptEnabled="True"
                  Margin="0,0,0,34" 
                  Foreground="Cyan"/>
```

But its not working.

Please help.
Thanx in advance to all.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change anything in the `WebBrowser` control you'll have to do it in the content (HTML/CSS) that you load into the control.

Answer (score 0):

One option you might have to get what you seem to want: set `Opacity` of the `WebBrowser` below 1 so the background of the element the `WebBrowser` is on top off shines through. This you can then set to your wanted cyan to give the entire HTML content a cyan tint, as if seen through cyan tinted glasses. Might this help, perhaps?